# Blazor как создавать объекты с большим количеством навигационных свойств?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

Вопрос в следующем, есть такие модели: https://pastebin.com/HAVRWqUW
Как правильно создавать заказ (MAOrder) со стороны UI? Все остальные классы (Статус, категория и пр.) хранятся тоже в базе, соответственно их нужно доставать из базы тоже.
Пытался разбить каждый класс на отдельный компонент (в примере для статусов), чтобы можно было его встраивать в разметку страницы (создания и редактирования), но получилось как-то не очень:

```html
@inject IOrderStatusesRepository repository

@if (statuses != null && statuses.Count > 0)
{
    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <select @bind="@SelectedId" class="form-select">
            <option value="" selected>-- Не выбран статус --</option>
            @foreach (var item in statuses)
            {
                <option value="@item.Id">@item.Name</option>
            }
        </select>
        <label class="form-label">Статус заказа</label>
    </div>
}
else if (statuses != null && statuses.Count == 0)
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger">Нет статусов для заказов</div>
}

@code {
    List<MAOrderStatus>? statuses;

    public int? SelectedId { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        statuses = await repository.GetAllAsync();
    }
}
```

Вопрос в том, как правильно и лучше сделать создание такого большого объекта? Можно ли сделать какое-то поэтапное создание заказа? Чтобы открывалась страница с выбором статуса, потом с выбором категории и пр., в конце создание позиций?
PS: .NET 6

Answer (score 0):

У вас есть 2 варианта: создание большого объекта или поэтапное(правильное). На хабре были статьи про UI и про ваш пример(большой объект) точно также рекомендовалось разбивать его на этапы. Не как вы предлагаете по статусам, категориям и.т.п, а разделите его на 2-3 смысловые части. На главной странице сперва загрузите все нужные вам данные, а затем передавайте их в ваши компоненты, например, через параметры [Parameter] и OnParametersSet/OnParametersSetAsync. Саму статью попробую найти.

В material есть такой компонент [stepper](https://material.io/archive/guidelines/components/steppers.html#). Для wpf библиотеки materialdesign есть расширяющая [либа](https://github.com/spiegelp/MaterialDesignExtensions) и в ней реализован данный компонент. Попробуйте, потестируйте его и можете сделать что-то похожее и удобное для пользователя.

Ну и немного не по теме:

1. Почему в MAOrder, MAOrderPosition рядом с каждой сущностью есть ее id? Зачем нужен id, если его можно получить из Worker.Id, когда **правильно** настроены связи между сущностями? Например:

```
  public ApplicationUser? Worker { get; set; }
  public string? WorkerId { get; set; }
```

2. Вам не нравятся бесплатные сторонние библиотеки компонентов? Их [много](https://medium.com/@alexandre.malavasi/top-10-nice-free-blazor-components-b42875e56b28). Я лично использую [MudBlazor](https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/).

Comment: Почему-то, когда сохраняю объект через навигационные св-ва Worker и пр., то выкидывает ошибку. EF пытается создать их еще раз, хотя в базе они есть. Связи настроены, вроде как, правильно, но могу ошибаться: https://pastebin.com/9DGtEFt2

Comment: Со страницей создания/редактирования уже подсказали, делал не правильно, зачем-то брал @ref (ссылку) на компонент и руками из него тянул данные в объект. Переделал на интерфейсы и теперь компонент требует в себя ссылку на объект с реализацией определенного интерфейса и записывает выбранное значение сразу в него.

Comment: @LiptonDev в EF не силен, но поначалу делал точно также через builder и указывал напрямую связи между сущностями(+ еще и virtual). Вроде как работало, но иногда возникали непонятные ситуации(особенно при удалении). Плюнул и полностью убрал указание связей через builder. Теперь объявляю их напрямую в сущностях. На метаните более подробно: https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/3.2.php Мой пример: https://pastebin.com/M6aHyZGF В дочерней указываем родительский класс + Id к имени. Так EF понимает, как им делать связи.

Comment: Ну объекты из базы я не удаляю вообще, а помечаю их как удаленные (IsDeleted=true), поэтому проблем с удалением у меня не будет)  
В целом и мой код тоже работает, пока никаких ошибок не нашел, а virtual не пишу потому что lazy loading не нужен, если навигационные св-ва нужны, то я просто возьму их через Include